# How can I make an object move randomly

Tags: java

I'm making a game where I spawn enemies at the top of the screen, they move downwards to the bottom of the screen. I want to make them move randomdly.

```
public void move_randomly(){

    int random_x_pos = rd.nextInt(700);

    if (xPos < random_x_pos){
        xPos += get_speed();
        if (xPos >= random_x_pos){
           // get a new x position
        }
    }
    if (xPos > random_x_pos){
        xPos -= get_speed();
        if(xPos >= random_x_pos){
            // get a new x position
        }
    }

    yPos += get_speed();  //makes the object keep moving down
}
```

The problem is that this method has to be called inside an infinite loop, the one that is constantly repainting the screen, so *the random_x_position* variable is always changing. I want the random X position given to be "saved" until the object has reached that position and then change it.

Comment: Create a "entity", which contains the x/y information and contains the logic for updating it's position based on the boundary conditions and how to paint itself. When you spawn a new enemy, you basically create a new "enemy entity", place it in a `List` and manage it as thus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a class variable and store the instance until you need to  change it. You would initialize the variable when you create the class, and then update it as needed. It might look like:

```
public class YourClass{
    int random_x_pos;
    publice YourClass(){
         random_x_pos = rd.nextInt(700);
    }

    ...
public void moveRandomly(){
    //use your variable
    random_x_position...
    if(conditionMet){
         random_x_postion = rd.nextInt(700);
    }
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of a "cool down" so it moves in that direction for a certain amount of time.  You check if cool down time has run up using System.currentTimeMillis().

```
protected double moveCoolDownTime=.2*1000;

public void randomMove() {
    double currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((currentTime-movedTime)>=moveCoolDownTime) {
            speed=random.nextInt(10)-10;
        }
        movedTime=currentTime;
    }
}

    //in your update method
    xPos -= get_speed();
```